# List of Exchange 2007 Mailbox attributes(properties) using by powershell command?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to list exchange 2007 mailbox attributes (using powershell), which can be set using powershell command (Enable-Mailbox). Do you know how I can do this?

I know the list of parameters are here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998251%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx, could there be any custom parameters which is not listed here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:

```
get-mailbox
```

[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123685%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)

Edit after comments:

```
set-mailbox mailboxname | Get-member | ? { $_.membertype -eq "Property"} # give all properties usable with se-mailbox commandlet


Get-Mailbox | Get-member | ? { $_.membertype -eq "Property"} #This give a list of all properties available from the Get-mailbox cmdlet
```

Comment: Tried. If I do not specify Identity in this command it returns me a list of all mailboxes(it is a lot of info). Specifying the Identity is not acceptable for me. I need only property names which I get while using this command for one mailbox

Comment: Get-Mailbox | Get-member | ? { $_.membertype -eq "Property"} #This give a list of properties available from the Get-mailbox cmdlet

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian, that is exactly what I need